# How to limit a negating (emacs-compatible) regex to the negated string

Tags: regex, emacs, regex-negation

I am looking for a regex which does not match "`CVS`". **I don't want to use any feature which cannot translate into Emacs regex.**

So far I have (in Python syntax, because I want to show it on regex101.com):

[`(^[^C].*|^.[^V].*|^..[^S].*)`](https://regex101.com/r/cW6qzK/2/tests)

This regex does *not* match "`CVS`" - so far so good. Unfortunately it does *not* match "`CVS and more`" either, but it should match it.

How can I adjust my regex to match "`CVS and anything after it`", but still not match "`CVS`"? (I.e how can I make the last test on the [regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/cW6qzK/2/tests) succeed?)

Comment: is look behind supported in regex engine you're using ?

Comment: is this what you're after, [check this](https://regex101.com/r/cW6qzK/3/tests)

Comment: @CodeManiac To your 1st comment: I don't think Emacs support look-behind.

Comment: @CodeManiac To your 2nd comment: Your regex does not succeed the first test (i.e. it *does* match `CVS`  which it should not match).

Comment: @Emma No. I need a regex which does *not* match the string "CVS", but matches the strings  "CVS and more", "xVS", "CxS","CVx", "any other string", etc... (See the [tests on  regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cW6qzK/2/tests): All test succeed, only the last one does not - to make that one succeed *as well*, is my question.)

Comment: `M-x flush-lines <return> CVS$`

Comment: @Drew I really need the regex, because in `ediff-directories` I want to use this regex to *exclude* the peski CVS directories littered around everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to match every individual line which isn't the line:

```
CVS
```

You're not too far off with your attempt.

Here the regex in Python syntax on regex101.com:

[`^(?:[^C\n]|C[^V\n]|CV[^S\n]|CVS.).*|^CV?$`](https://regex101.com/r/cW6qzK/9)

And here's an elisp regexp in the read syntax for strings:

```
"^\\(?:[^C\n]\\|C[^V\n]\\|CV[^S\n]\\|CVS.\\).*\\|^CV?$"
```

Note the newlines.  So in string syntax it becomes:

```
^\(?:[^C
]\|C[^V
]\|CV[^S
]\|CVS.\).*\|^CV?$
```

n.b. You can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `re-builder` to test these in Emacs.

Comment: Cool. Makes sense. Will test it out tomorrow.

Comment: Just noticed  the regex is still not right. Look at the string "CV" (without the S) - I want the regex to match it, but it doesn't match. Check the added test on the updated [regex101 page](https://regex101.com/r/cW6qzK/7).

Comment: Right you are.  Obviously `C` on its own would fail as well.  Let's suffix that regexp with `\|^CV?$`.  Answer updated.

Comment: I've added a mention of `re-builder` as well.  If you're unfamiliar with that, you may also find this useful: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5568/454

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes, all working now. Even "C" matches correctly (although it is not mentioned as an explicit cas in the regex).

Comment: Note that `CV?` means `C` *optionally* followed by `V`, so that covers both cases.